# проблема с анимацией 3d flip

Tags: html, css

```css
#main,
#footer {
  width: 1700px;
  height: 1080px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  width: 340px;
  height: 1080px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-transform: perspective(1200px);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.back {
  width: 340px;
  height: 1080px;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 180deg, rgb(94, 94, 94) 0%, rgb(178, 78, 78) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 180deg, rgb(94, 94, 94) 0%, rgb(78, 78, 78) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 180deg, rgb(94, 94, 94) 0%, rgb(78, 78, 78) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1080px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}

.flipper {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 1020px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: .7s linear;
  -moz-transition: .7s linear;
  -o-transition: .7s linear;
  transition: .7s linear;
}

.back:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}

.front:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.head {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px 0 0 40px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(2, 75, 157);
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 40px 20px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container:hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="head" id="headOne">упаковочное оборудование</div>
    <div class="flipper">
      <a href="one.html"></a>
      <div class="front">
        <img src="images/block1.png">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <ul>
          <li>горизонтальное</li>
          <li>вертикальное</li>
          <li>трейсилеры</li>
          <li>термоусадочное</li>
          <li>термоформовочное</li>
          <li>паллетоупаковщики</li>
          <li>вакуумное</li>
          <li>упаковка на подложку</li>
          <li>упаковка длинномерных изделий</li>
          <li>клипсаторы</li>
          <li>обвязчики мягкими лентами</li>
          <li>формовщики коробов</li>
          <li>заклейщики коробов скотчем</li>
          <li>весовое</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы синий блок не исчезал на половину при воспроизведении анимации? 
Пробовал поместить его над контейнером с меню, но в таком случае при переходе на другие страницы он остается на месте.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Так и как в итоге синий блок должен вести себя?

Comment: Он должен быть поверх анимации. Т.е. при анимации меню не должен исчезать на половину.

Answer (score -1):

Решил сам.

В контейнере, в `transform-style "preserve-3d"` надо заменить на `"flat"`.